# Run cuffcompare in strand-agnostic mode

Tags: rna-seq, transcriptome, strandedness

Is there a way to run Cufflinks' [cuffcompare](http://cole-trapnell-lab.github.io/cufflinks/cuffcompare/) in a strand-agnostic mode?

I would like to do this because I have some RNA-seq datasets derived from an unstranded run, that should be compared to a reference transcriptome. I think that it makes no reason to have some transcripts in the experimental dataset classified with transfrag code tag `x` and `s` as compared to the reference if the input dataset was not derived from stranded protocol.

From [manual](http://cole-trapnell-lab.github.io/cufflinks/cuffcompare/#transfrag-class-codes):

> x : Exonic overlap with reference on the opposite strand
>
> s : An intron of the transfrag overlaps a reference intron on the opposite strand (likely due to read mapping errors)

Conceptually, does it make sense?

If so, and if the run by cuffcompare cannot be changed to a strand-agnostic manner, how should I interprete those transcripts classified as `x`? I was thinking of merging them to `o` and/or `c` .

Again, from manual:

> c :   Contained
>
> o :   Generic exonic overlap with a reference transcript